# Ansible seems to ignore ansible_shell_type when set by set_fact

Tags: ansible

I have a playbook that first creates a virtual machine on a vSphere cluster. It uses `hosts: localhost` so the API is called by the ansible-runner. Creation of VM works fine. After the VM is created and up, I want to call a powershell script on the created VM.

At this point I run into below issue:

```
{
  "unreachable": true,
  "msg": "Failed to create temporary directory. In some cases, you may have been able to authenticate and did not have permissions on the target directory. Consider changing the remote tmp path in ansible.cfg to a path rooted in \"/tmp\", for more error information use -vvv. Failed command was: ( umask 77 && mkdir -p \"` echo ~/.ansible/tmp `\"&& mkdir \"` echo ~/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1641299382.7315738-32-66906511694241 `\" && echo ansible-tmp-1641299382.7315738-32-66906511694241=\"` echo ~/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1641299382.7315738-32-66906511694241 `\" ), exited with result 1",
  "changed": false
}
```

It seems the play thinks it executes on a Linux machine. That's not curious at all, because `gather_facts` is set to `false` in the playbook. So the play cannot know it is a Windows VM.

I tried to mitigate that issue by firing below task before, but the issue remains the same.

```yaml
- name: set shell type
  set_fact:
    ansible_shell_type: powershell
```

I also tried by also setting os_family before, without success.

```yaml
- name: set os fam
  set_fact:
    ansible_os_family: 'Windows'
```

When I fire this task before, it correctly shows "powershell".

```
- name: DEBUG ansible_shell_type
  debug: 
    var: ansible_shell_type
```

I am a little bit lost now, it looks like the task does not make use of `ansible_shell_type`.

```yaml
- name: Windows - Regenerate ssh host keys
  ansible.windows.win_powershell:
    script: |
      del "C:\ProgramData\ssh\ssh_host_*"
      ssh-keygen.exe -A
      $Account = New-Object -TypeName System.Security.Principal.NTAccount -ArgumentList 'NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM';
      $ItemList = Get-ChildItem -Path C:\ProgramData\ssh\ssh_host_* -Recurse;
      foreach ($Item in $ItemList) {
          $Acl = $null; # Reset the $Acl variable to $null
          $Acl = Get-Acl -Path $Item.FullName;
          $Acl.SetOwner($Account);
          $Acl.SetGroup($Account);
          Set-Acl -Path $Item.FullName -AclObject $Acl;
      }
  delegate_to: "{{ vm_ip_address }}"
```

Using `- meta: reset_connection` before does not make any difference, too.

I'm kinda lost right now. Hope anyone of you has an idea what I missed.

Comment: Have you simply tried to set `ansible_shell_type` in the `vars` section directly in the powershell task ? You should also probably prefer using `add_host` to add your newly created vm to the in-memory inventory and then play the task directly on that target in the next play. While making guesses.... didn't you force `connection: local` on your play where that task is played ?

Comment: Thanks a lot, adding the var to the vars section of the task did the trick. It works now.

Comment: Please do not edit question with fixes. You are welcome to self answer the question if you feel it can help others.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to Zeitounator!

The fix is as easy as adding vars directly to the task. The below result works as expected:

```
- name: Windows - Regenerate ssh host keys
  ansible.windows.win_powershell:
    script: |
      del "C:\ProgramData\ssh\ssh_host_*"
      ssh-keygen.exe -A
      $Account = New-Object -TypeName System.Security.Principal.NTAccount -ArgumentList 'NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM';
      $ItemList = Get-ChildItem -Path C:\ProgramData\ssh\ssh_host_* -Recurse;
      foreach ($Item in $ItemList) {
          $Acl = $null; # Reset the $Acl variable to $null
          $Acl = Get-Acl -Path $Item.FullName;
          $Acl.SetOwner($Account);
          $Acl.SetGroup($Account);
          Set-Acl -Path $Item.FullName -AclObject $Acl;
      }
  delegate_to: "{{ vm_ip_address }}"
  vars:
    ansible_shell_type: powershell
```